# How can I write into a file within an Eclipse bundle?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, bundle

I have an xml configuration file located into my plugin resources. I want to update this file whenever in the plugin happens some event. I found some methods to find and read the contents of a file located my plugin classpath, but I'm looking for a way to write into such a file.

Is there any way?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That location (the install directory) is intended to be read-only since it may be shared in a network install scenario.  I suggest you instead write the XML file to your plugin's state location which is intended for just this purpose:

```
String path = Activator.getDefault().getStateLocation().toString();
```

I should add that this gives you a fully qualified path to the directory created by Eclipse for any files your plugin wants to store.  This directory is unique to your plugin.